# jQuery selector not running inside function called by ajaxcomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to replace some text in an element that is created dynamically.

I tried:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
       console.log('I started');
       $(".classname:contains('foo')").html('bar');
       console.log('I finished');
 })
```

The function starts and finishes just when I want it to, but the selection and replacement never happens.

If I just run the replacement in the console, after the element exists, it works fine:

```
> $(".classname:contains('foo')").html('bar')
> [<label class=​"classname" for=​"element">bar​</label>​]
```

As does just running the selection and replace constantly with:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {$(".classname:contains('foo')").html('bar')})
```

How can I get my jQuery to run only when I need it to?

Comment: Make sure the ajax `global` option is not set to `false`, or else `ajaxComplete` will not be called.

Comment: Adding elements to the DOM can take a little bit of time, sometimes if you add an element then immediately search for it it wont find it. I am assuming that $(".classname:contains('foo')") is being added with the ajax call. The only solution I have found is to add a setTimeout to delay the action by a frame.

Comment: So `.classname:contains('foo')` are appended in the DOM dynamically following an ajax request? If ya (or not...), provide relevant code in question itself

Comment: @Ignaus it is being called, the console.logs show that.

Comment: @Rolyataylor2 But shouldn't the selector return null in the console then? It doesn't seem like it's running at all. I can do other jQuery selectors for things that existed all along and they don't run either.

Comment: @A.Wolff I would love to, but unfortunately the element isn't created until you can log into to the system in question, and you can't. Sorry.

Comment: If you are running the selector in the console yourself(manually) it would be well after the element was added to the DOM. Try debugging using `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { console.log($(".classname:contains('foo')")); });` with chrome if it outputs the elements in the ajax request then I am stumped, if it outputs `[]` or if it outputs `[old discarded elements]` then it is happening before the DOM is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it seems that it should work.

```
$(function () {
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
       console.log('I started');
       $(".classname:contains('foo')").html('bar');
       console.log('I finished');
   });
   $.get('www.example.com');
});
```

You can see it in an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0g3dmnfc/

Maybe you should wrap it in onready.